# Varistor in a DC circuit

Tags: dc, varistor

I'm employing a Varistor in a simple circuit that will be used in a car. The Varistor is there to ensure that any load dumps / vehicle transients will not result in catastrophe for the circuit.

My question is this: **Should I pass VIN through the Varistor, or should the Varistor couple VIN and GND?**

Circuit A has VIN passing through the Varistor:
[image]

Circuit B has the Varistor tied from VIN to GND:

[image]

Comment: These schematics are not very logically shown. with IN?OUT?Vin and orientation. of shunt device being horizontal wrap around before fuse

Comment: Apologies, you're right -- I need to fix my symbols and placement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The fuse would always be before voltage-surge "shunt" clamp protection shown as Z_suppressor.

The other series elements are the Z (resistance+inductance) of the source and lines.

[REFERENCE](https://www.littelfuse.com/~/media/electronics/application_notes/littelfuse_tvs_diode_automotive_circuit_protection_using_automotive_tvs_diodes_application_note.pdf.pdf)

Comment: Thank you! So I need to move the fuse and then the Varistor will need to be placed between VIN and GND, as poorly shown in schematic "B".

Comment: Yes.  Fuse panel locations are designed to minimize Z to surge generating devices like solenoids and ACU clutches  thus higher inductance to sensitive peripherals with longer leads

Comment: I have updated the schematic for circuit "B" so it's a bit less garbage. Also, that's great to know, thank you!